# Group by almost all attributes

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I have a table with 20 columns. I need to group them by all columns except the last one.

```
SELECT att1, att2, att3, ..., att19, sum(att20)
FROM table
GROUP BY att1, att2, att3, ..., att19;
```

But is there a shorter way to write it instead of listing all attributes?

I tried

```
SELECT 1,2,3,...,19, sum(att20)
FROM table
GROUP BY 1,2,3,...,19;
```

I wonder if there is something like

```
SELECT * (except att20), sum(att20)
FROM table
GROUP BY * (except att20);
```

Comment: Nope, you'll have to list all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But is there a shorter way to write it instead of listing all attributes?

No there is no other way. You have to list all the columns explicitly.

The other workaround which I can think of is to insert the data into a temporary table containing all the 19 columns(*leaving the one which you dont want*) and then simply do it like this:

```
select distinct * from #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to doing it. You have to write all column in group by and select statement.